# Identical splash screen after loading and before webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So, i have a webview in which i load an ad everytime the app starts, this is the first viewController in the main navigation controller and its the one that launches the home viewController after the ad, the problem is, after the splash screen and before the ad is finish loading, the webview is hidden at first and when loaded then is visible, beneath the webview is an uiimage with constraints to fill the entire view. the image is the same as the splash screen (portrait or landscape), but when the transition from the splash intro to the first viewcontroller begin, the imageview looks offset in comparison to the ios splash image, so im guessing it has to do with the status bar at the top? i have tried many combination of constrains and sizes and i cant seem to find a way to achieve a non-jumpy transition from the splash to my first uiimageview filling the whole view.

this is what im trying to achieve.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33305929/intro.png

the whole thing is already done the only problem is the jumpy not perfect transition from the intro splash screen to my uiimageview in the first viewcontroller, any ideas? has anybody faced the same issue, any suggestion is much appreciated. thanks for your time.

note: the uiimageview has constraints for top, bottom, left and right of the layout. i also tried with no constraints with no luck.

Comment: I made the intro viewController as an xib file, with contraints, nothing fancy, the navigation controller is in a stantard storyboard and i just do:

UiNavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"main_navigation_controller"];

[navigationController setViewControllers:@[intro_view] animated:NO];

in the app delegate.

Comment: I would suggest not to show image with WebView, there are chances of delay in the appearance of the image, try using UIViewController instead, and show UIImageView until ad has been loaded.

Comment: thats exactly what i do, please read the question carefully. My problem comes from the ios(splash screen) to the uiimageview in my intro view, they dont look identical in the transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was the resolution of the image that ios was using in the splash screen.
from ipad2 and ipad mini, it should be the normal (768,1024) version of the splash, for ipad Air and retina displays the image for splash is the @2X version.